# POST isset query in an infinite loop

Tags: php, mysql, account

I'm creating an account creation form submission PHP script. However, the query goes in an infinite loop. It continuously adds entries into the database until I close the page. Why does it do this? Thanks so much!

```
<?php require 'dbconnect.php'; ?>
<?php
    //If sign up submit POST recieved
    if (isset($_POST['suEmail']))
    {
        $suFirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['suFirstName']); 
        $suLastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['suLastName']); 
        $suEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['suEmail']); 
        $suPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['suPassword']);
        $suDisplayName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['suDisplayName']);
        $confirmCode = substr(md5(mt_rand()),0,15);

        $query = $connection->query("INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,email,password,displayName,confirmCode,verified)Values('{$suFirstName}','{$suLastName}','{$suEmail}','{$suPassword}','{$suDisplayName}','{$confirmCode}','0')");

        if ($query)
        {
            echo "query SUCCESS";
            $subject = "Learncyclopedia Email Verification";
            $headers = "From: noreply@learncyclopedia.com \r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: noreply@learncyclopedia.com \r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

            $message = '<html><body>';
            $message.='<div style="width:550px; background-color:#CC6600; padding:15px; font-weight:bold;">';
            $message.='Learncyclopedia Email Verification';
            $message.='</div>';
            $message.='<div style="font-family: Arial;">Hello '.$suFirstName.'<br/>';
            $message.='Click on the link below to verify your account<br>';
            $message.="<a href='http://79.170.40.236/learncyclopedia.com/user-confirmation.php?email=$suEmail&confirmation_code=$confirmCode'>click</a>";
            $message.='</div>';
            $message.='</body></html>';

            mail("123@gmail.com",$subject,$message,$headers);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This isn't `dbconnect.php`, is it? This is your exact code? If you swap the `query` with `echo` you get non-stop output?

Comment: This isnt dbconnect.php, dbconnect is my connection file. No, I don't get nonstop output when I replace the query with echo. However, when I keep it normal it continuously places entries in my database until I close the page. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check your submit button name. I think you messed up with this

> suEmail,   $suEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['suEmail']);